# Start Docker container immediately after creation?

Tags: docker

Is there's an option to start a container immediately on creation? Looking through the [Create a Container](http://docs.docker.io/en/master/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.9/#create-a-container) docs I can't see one, but I suspect something like this may already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you take the container id from the response of [Create a Container](http://docs.docker.io/en/master/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.9/#create-a-container), then pass it into [Start a Container](http://docs.docker.io/en/master/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.9/#start-a-container)?

Comment: Adding detail from the links would really improve the answer. Links break and that means the answer is no longer useful.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing as @dannyla mentions. Using Dockerode:

```
async.waterfall([
  function createContainer(cb){
    log('Creating container')
    // http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.9/#create-a-container
    docker.createContainer({
      // Exposedports, Cmd, etc come from image
      Image: imageName,
      name: containerName
    }, cb);
  },

  function startContainer(container, cb){
    // http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.9/#start-a-container
    log('Starting new container')
    container.start(cb)
  }

] .... )
```

Added as as answer because sample code could be useful.